# Tomcat infinte loop on requestDispatcher#forward(). StackOverflowError

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, requestdispatcher, deployment-descriptor

Tomcat is giving me StackOverflowError after constantly repeating these lines, where `DiceBoardDispatcher` is my HttpServlet and in line 34 I am calling `requestDispatcher#forward()`.

```
nl.rickhurkens.rollDice.web.diceBoard.DiceBoardDispatcher.doGet(DiceBoardDispatcher.java:34)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        nl.rickhurkens.rollDice.web.diceBoard.DiceBoardDispatcher.doGet(DiceBoardDispatcher.java:34)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I guess it's got something to do with my deployment, here is the relevant part of my web.xml:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiceBoard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dices/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RollDiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/dices/roll</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetSettingsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/dices/setup</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

What I am trying to do is have 2 actions both landing on the same page. I thought I'd set it up like this. Each action goes through its own `Filter` and they both end in the `Servlet` that dispatches to a `JSP`.

My url-patter mapping used to be to `/diceBoard/*`, which is a folder somewhere in the web-app. Changing from there to `/dices/*` fixed the problem when going to `url/dices`. Now I can reach that page normally, but when going to `url/dices/roll` I get the infinite loop (no matter if POST or GET).

Edit:
My servlet code:

```
public class DiceBoardDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("diceBoardPage.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("diceBoardPage.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And RollDiceFilter:

```
public class RollDiceFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        DiceBoard diceBoard = (DiceBoard)session.getAttribute("diceBoard");
        String[] lockedValues = req.getParameterValues("lock");

        diceBoard.unlockAllDice();
        if (lockedValues != null) {
            for (String value : lockedValues) {
                if (value != null) {
                    try {
                        diceBoard.lockDice(Integer.parseInt(value));
                    } catch (DiceNotInCollectionException e) {
                        // TODO: redirect to error page.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        diceBoard.getCup().roll();

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException { }
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

Comment: **Where** is your servlet dispatching a forward to? Post the relevant lines of your code, please.

Comment: I have now posted the relevant code. I thought it had something to do with [this](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5599), that's why I didn't think the code was very relevant for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line where your error is located:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("diceBoardPage.jsp");
```

According to the [getRequestDispatcher API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)), the input uri is *relative* to the current servlet context, so when you are executing your servlet at

```
/dices/roll
```

... and it performs a dispatch to "diceBoardPage.jsp", it is actually dispatching to

```
/dices/diceBoardPage.jsp
```

And what servlet is mapped this pattern to? According to your deployment descriptor, every URL beginning with "/dices/*" is mapped to `DiceBoard`. I.E. the same servlet. Here comes the infinite loop that caused your StackOverflowError.

If the JSP must stay within the `dices` uri, you must restrict the URL pattern which maps the `DiceBoard` servlet. Do not hesitate to add several values if needed:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DiceBoard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dices/one</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/dices/two</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/dices/three</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out as well. I changed to argument to getRequestDispatcher() to `/diceBoardPage.jsp`, so now it is relative to the context root. Thanks for your help and for teaching me I can supply multiple <url-patterns> !